# pickle can't import a module that exists?

Tags: python, module, import, pickle

Why might this happen?

```
import window; print "LOADED"; data = cPickle.loads(data)
```

The result is:

```
LOADED
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    import window; print "LOADED"; data = cPickle.loads(data)
exceptions.ImportError: No module named window
```

It loads the module fine if I do `import window`, but when loading with `cPickle` it doesn't seem to work.

For some additional info which is likely relevant:

The module I saved the file in is in `project1\MODULE\submodule\main.py`. The `window` module is `project1\MODULE\window.py`. `main.py` begins:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..\\..")
sys.path.append("..")
...
import window
```

The module I'm attempting to load from is in `project2\project2sub\MODULE\data.py`, with no messing with the `sys` path.

`MODULE` is the same in both cases: the module I want to load is `project2\project2sub\MODULE\window.py`.

Could the `sys.path` appending mess this up somehow?

Comment: What is **IN** the 'data'?  What is being pickled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pickle depends upon the module path. No matter how you load modules, if you don't mess with `sys.path`, pickle loading and saving should work. However, if you do `import module.foo` in one place, and `sys.path.append('module'); import foo`, you have two different module paths: in the first instance the module path is `module.foo` while in the second it is just `foo`. These are not equivalent and that'll prevent pickle from working properly.

Comment: Omg your explanation resolved my one-week lasted problem. My mistake was the exact thing that you have described. Even though I had __init__ file under my subfolder, I could not import those files. Then I applied to sys.path.append solution. As it turns out, it caused even a bigger problem! Thank you sincerely.

Answer (score 6):

Check to make sure that you're importing classes in the *loading* programing in the same manner as you are in the *saving* program.

Saving:

```
 import window
 myObj.window_obj = window.wObj
```

Loading

```
 import window
 myObj = cPickle.loads(data)
```

**NOT:**

Saving:

```
 from window import wObj
 myObj.window_obj = wObj
```

Loading:

```
 import window
 myObj = cPickle.loads(data)
```

Comment: i have a feeling both those would work. i think the issue was that in one i did `import module.foo` (effectively). in the other i did `sys.path.append('module'); import foo` (effectively). thus the path is different (`foo` vs. `module/foo`) and that is messing it up.

Comment: @Claudiu:
I had the same problem (and solution) can you post this as an answer, and accept it? (so others can find)