# Flask + sklearn can't joblib.load AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, joblib

Flask application. 
I trying to **joblib.load** and get **AttributeError 'ManyToOneClassifier'**.
But I already imported all modules with class.
And if I'll try to load it in module with class in module with it... again error. 
But when I load it in __ main __ - fine, all works... When upload, **uwsgi** doesn't see anything in my __ main __. 
I am C# programmer (.NET, Microsoft and so on) not so much exp with nginx & Linux.

```
from clf_service import app, classificator

from clf_service.classificator import ManyClassifier, ManyToOneClassifier

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from os import path


application = app

APP_ROOT = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))

print "Loading models"
app.model = joblib.load(path.join(APP_ROOT, "clf_service/static/ml/clf/model_vec_to_one.pkl"))
app.vec = joblib.load(path.join(APP_ROOT, "clf_service/static/ml/clf/vec_to_one.pkl"))
print "Done, we are ready!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

__ init __.py

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask


application = Flask(__name__)
app = application
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from clf_service import views, models, classificator
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050391/pickle-cant-import-a-module-that-exists this link might be helpful.