# Does loading a pickle import the object's module?

Tags: python, pickle

I was under the impression that loading an object (that's not of one of the built-in types) from a pickle will import the module. For example, 
[pickle can't import a module that exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050391/pickle-cant-import-a-module-that-exists) indicates that module correponding to the type of the object being unpicked must exist at the same path.

However, when I try to unpickle a NumPy ndarray, the unpickling worked fine, but the module does not seem to be imported:

```
In [12]: with open('numpysample.pkl', 'rb') as input:
    ...:     a = pickle.load(input)

In [14]: type(a)
Out[14]: numpy.ndarray

In [13]: numpy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-8d40275025d1> in <module>
----> 1 numpy

NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pickle imports the module. Just not into that name space. `'numpy' in sys.modules` will be false before the `pickle.load` call and true after.

> is it correct to say that there is no namespace into which numpy is imported?

The source of `pickle.Unpickler.find_class` should answer this.

```
    def find_class(self, module, name):
        # Subclasses may override this
        __import__(module)
        mod = sys.modules[module]
        klass = getattr(mod, name)
        return klass
```

During this method the module those name is in `module` is bound to `mod` during the scope of this function.

Comment: And note, `import numpy` after loading the pickle will go very quickly because of this; it doesn't actually import `numpy` again, it just grabs the cached import from `sys.modules`.

Comment: Thanks; I tried out `sys.modules` and it is indeed as you say. I understand pickle imports `numpy`, but is it correct to say that there is no namespace into which `numpy` is imported? I say this because there is no name binding to the module (which is referenced as a value in the `sys.modules` dict only).

Comment: This made it clear for me. Since `__import__()` does not bind the name of the to-be-loaded module, and `mod` is not accessible from outside, there isn't a name we can use to directly refer to the class/module of the unpicked object. But I guess we also know this from `dir()` or `globals()`.